# how to select and display the item from ionic list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi Im trying to create a number list using ionic list. Im trying to display the selected number from the list, example if number two is selected the output should be you have selected number 2. I face difficulty in displaying the selected number from the list.Please help me to get it correct. [image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPQed.png)

html code:

```
      <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="(key,item) in Number"> 
        < div ng-click="select-item(key)">
      {{item.value}}</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.description = '';
  $scope.selectedItem = 'select';
   $scope.Number=['1','2','3','4','5'];
  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    if ($scope.carList[key]) {
      $scope.carList[key].selected = true;
      { { item.value } }
    }
```

If anything is wrong please correct me.Thank you.

Comment: how do you want to show your output ? and also please provide some of your relevent code for this .Thanks

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik i have attached a sample code. If anything is wrong please do correct me, since I'm new to ionic and struggling to get things right.

Comment: @jazzoria - please post your Config.js file to check which type of routing you used for page then only i can provide solution

Answer (score 0):

There are various mistakes , change your html

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-click="select_item(number)" ng-repeat="number in Number">
        {{number}}
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Then In your controller

```
$scope.description = '';
  $scope.selectedItem = 'select';
   $scope.Number=['1','2','3','4','5'];
  $scope.select_item = function (key) {
    alert(key);
     }
```

You were using wrong function name , and you cant use {{item.value}} in your js. hope this helps you (y)